# Build a heatmap in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, heatmap

**The DataFrame below includes information about launchung of a program.**

```
          week           day    number of launchings    
2016-12-19 - 2016-12-25  Mon              70
2016-12-19 - 2016-12-25  Tue              91
2016-12-19 - 2016-12-25  Wed              117
2016-12-19 - 2016-12-25  Thu              57
2016-12-19 - 2016-12-25  Fri              33
2016-12-19 - 2016-12-25  Sat              38
2016-12-19 - 2016-12-25  Sun              27
2016-12-26 - 2017-01-01  Mon              52
2016-12-26 - 2017-01-01  Tue              52
2016-12-26 - 2017-01-01  Wed              41
2016-12-26 - 2017-01-01  Thu              60
2016-12-26 - 2017-01-01  Fri              25
2016-12-26 - 2017-01-01  Sat              12
2016-12-26 - 2017-01-01  Sun              51
                     ...
```

**I need to get a heatmap with the next structure:**

[image]

Comment: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this but I can't make the heatmap from the 4th example, it returned an error and I desided to use pandas as a more complex tool

Comment: Even using a pandas dataframe to store the data, the code should work. What is the error you were getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the seaborn package to make pretty nice heatmaps.Assuming your data as you have above is stored in a pandas dataframe called df,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
df = df.pivot("week", "day", "number of launchings")
ax = sns.heatmap(df)
plt.show()
```

should give you what you're looking for. You might want to create a new column for weeks that are numbered 1,2,3... so that it would be easier to read

Comment: I used `df.set_index(['week'], inplace=True)` to get rid of the index column, I removed this string and everything started work perfectly. Thank you)

Comment: I noticed a problem: the order of days changes in heatmap, it's Fr, Mo, Sa, Su, Th, Tu, We

Comment: Try adding the line `df['day'] = pd.Categorical(df['day'], categories=['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat', 'Sun'], ordered=True)'` before the `df = df.pivot...` line